# How to automatically logout the Android app if it is not touched(inactive) for 30 mins?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an android app.I just want that if i don't touch (InActive)my app for 30 mins ,it automatically logout.I have Activity and fragment both files.I have googled a lot and implement many codes but no one worked out.So please kindly allow me a code which could do this.And please make it clear that in which Activity and fragment i need to implement that.I will be really very thankful to you.Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: first create thread that run for 30 min. Then check for user iteraction with both fragment and activity, if touch event occurs, then just cancel ongoing thread and create new thread and again check.

Comment: save your login status in sharedpreference run an alaram service ever 30 minutes. wipe the app data through code. It will reset your app to login

Comment: @HourGlass....I dnt want to logout after 30 mins of login,I want to logout after 30 mins of user interaction with app.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `Handler`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  private Handler refreshHandler;
  private Runnable runnable;

 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      refreshHandler = new Handler();
      runnable = new Runnable() {
         @Override
            public void run() {
            // logout
            }
      };
      refreshHandler.postDelayed(runnable, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 30);
   }

 @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        refreshHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        refreshHandler.postDelayed(runnable, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 30);
    }
 }
```

The above is for the logout after 30 minutes. Now you need to listen to the `TouchEvents` or anything else you want to make sure that the user is active. If the user is active, remove the `Runnable` which is waiting to run.

```
refreshHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

And with this you start it again

```
refreshHandler.postDelayed(runnable, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 30);
```

There is always a better and more elegant way to solve it, but this would be a fast approach.

Edit: I added the option via `onUserInteraction()`

> Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity. Implement this method if you wish to know that the user has interacted with the device in some way while your activity is running. This callback and onUserLeaveHint() are intended to help activities manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically, for helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notfication.
>
> All calls to your activity's onUserLeaveHint() callback will be accompanied by calls to onUserInteraction(). This ensures that your activity will be told of relevant user activity such as pulling down the notification pane and touching an item there.
>
> Note that this callback will be invoked for the touch down action that begins a touch gesture, but may not be invoked for the touch-moved and touch-up actions that follow.

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction())

Comment: I think the whole point of the question was how to detect inactivity.

Comment: @DmitryRyadnenko Oh I see. one sec

Comment: @DmitryRyadnenko Added an example

Comment: I just want that after login if i am in any activtiy/fragment or if i did not touch my app for 30 mins,it automatically logout.even if it is in foreground.

Comment: @Murat k..what i need to write in run() method //logout.

Comment: @AimuRiz The logout function you want to have. That's your code.

Comment: @Murat...For 1 min am i need to use 1 in place of 30?

Comment: @AimuRiz Yes you do.

Comment: hey@Murat..i have implemented your code.I put handler in onCreate and UserInteraction out of this in my MainActivity class but it didnt work.Please suggest now what i need to do?As i have only 2 activities which is Capture and Login,and many fragments.But i implemented it in only CaptureActivtiy.